# How to make the layout visible/gone?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an app using geolocation and I want to set a layout VISIBLE when close to a point and GONE when too far from the point.

This is my xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/slidePane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Then I use the ID in the activity as usual :
declare it in the class attribute :

```
private LinearLayout slidepane;
```

set it in the onCreate() method :

```
slidepane = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidePane);
```

And then I try to update it in `onLocationChanged()` method as follows :

```
if (InterestPoint.CalculationByDistance(location, new LatLng(47.247801, -1.551883)) < 0.03) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mContext, "InterestPoint close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    slidepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    slidepane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

So the condition is correct since the `Toast` appears but the layout does not become visible, why?

Thank you.

EDIT : I am using https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel and try to set the visibility of the second child (the sliding panel). I didn't see anything in the documentation about visibility. I can still access the children of the LinearLayout but not the container itself (and especialy the visibility).

Comment: First thing I would do is ensure the layout is actually visible in general.  Sometimes they can be pushed off-screen or behind another View.

Comment: if you set visibility visible in the xml can you see it?

Comment: Yes if I do not specify the "gone" visibility it is fully visible and functionnal.

Comment: ok so this is weird, one thing you could try is to set something other than visibility. for example, set visibility visible in the xml and instead of changing the visibility in your code change the background color and see if it works, your code seems ok

Comment: @Axl Try to increase the threshold and see if the code works.

Comment: @lelloman I tried with a textView instead before asking the question and the fact is I can update the textview visibility, text, size and so and so on bu not the LinearLayout which is really weird.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
slidepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

with this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        slidepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: it MIGHT solve the issue because the user is making UI change on `onLocationChanged()` which could be in a thread. If that is so, it won't change the UI. `runOnUiThread(..)` will

Comment: So you mean to say `onLocationChanged` is called on a background thread?

Comment: @th3pat3l Are u kidding us, `onLocationChange` does not work on BG thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the visibility of view at the time of initialization.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
........
slidepane = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidePane);    
slidepane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
.......

    //onLocationChanged() add ->

    if (InterestPoint.CalculationByDistance(location, new LatLng(47.247801, -1.551883)) < 0.03) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mContext, "InterestPoint close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    slidepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   } else {
    slidepane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
```

Comment: so by using `View.INVISIBLE`, you're just ignoring the user's preference to make the view GONE? View.INVISIBLE uses space on the screen while View.GONE doesn't. User chooses to make the view not take space. You're not giving a solution. you're changing the use case

Comment: I also tried to set it at the init but it made no change at all so I removed it since it is by default "gone" in the xml.

Comment: try doing with the last edited code of mine, INVISIBLE and VISIBLE

Comment: Sadly it didn't changed anything :/

Comment: did your `if` condition is true?

Comment: trace the `logcat`, just when you get the toast and paste here to see, whats happening with the view.

Comment: yes the condition is true, the toast proves it :)
Hum I don't understand what you want to see from the logcat ?